# Birkas Hachodesh when Rosh Chodesh is Shabbat and Sunday

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, nuschaot, rosh-chodesh-new-month

On [*Shabbat Mevarchim*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Shabbat#Shabbat_Mevorchim), *Birkas Hachodesh*, a prayer announcing when the *Rosh Chodesh* will be, is said after *Kriat Hatorah* before *Mussaf*, containing the following line (with some variations depending on the particular *nusach*):

> ראשׁ חדֶשׁ פלוני יִהְיֶה בְּיום פלוני הַבָּא עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשרָאֵל לְטובָה

When *Rosh Chodesh* will be for two days, both are mentioned:

> ראשׁ חדֶשׁ פלוני יִהְיֶה בְּיום פלוני וּבְּיום פלוני הַבָּא(ים) עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשרָאֵל לְטובָה

This past *Shabbat*, being *Shabbat Mevarchim* when *Rosh Chodesh* will be on the following *Shabbat* and Sunday, a member of the congregation reproved the *Chazzan*, who used the above *nusach*, claiming that when *Rosh Chodesh* will be on the following *Shabbat* and Sunday the *nusach* is changed slightly, and should be the following:

> ראשׁ חדֶשׁ פלוני יִהְיֶה בְּיום פלוני **ולמחרתו** בְּיום פלוני הַבָּא(ים) עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשרָאֵל לְטובָה

I had never heard of this before, but are there any sources which discuss the proper *nusach* for such a situation?

Comment: "Rosh Chodesh will be on the following Shabbat and Sunday" No, the following Sunday was not Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @DoubleAA When listing two consecutive days, the second usually refers to the day immediately following the first.

Comment: @Ploni It’s still a bit of a misleading line. I think AA’s answer is the correct one, and the better question IMHO is what’s the justification for *not* saying ולמחרתו.

Comment: @Ploni when they are consecutive sure, but these aren't consecutive. Did you mean specifically the Sunday following Shabbat? When you say "the Sunday following Shabbat" you remove all ambiguity.

Comment: @DoubleAA How are they not consecutive? Rosh Chodesh is always consecutive!

Comment: I have almost always heard the word ולמחרתו used for **every** 2-day Rosh Hodesh, regardless of which two days of the week they occur. I'm not seeing the problem being mentioned in the previous comments. The word ולמחרתו means, "and **its** morrow." Meaning the morrow of that Shabbat. I don't see how it can mean "tomorrow" meaning the immediate Sunday, or the day immediately after you just said this prayer. If you're really concerned, you can clarify the beginning by saying *Yom Shabbat Kodesh haba* so people don't think you mean today.

Comment: I've never heard anyone use the plural form of הַבָּא(ים). Doesn't the end of the phrase refer to Rosh Hodesh, and not the individual days? The term *Rosh Hodesh* as I understand refers to the entire unit, regardless of how long it is. Analogous - We don't use the plural for Rosh Hashanna even though it's two days long.

Comment: @DanF everyone *does* say Yom Shabbat Haba...

Comment: @DanF The problem mentioned in the previous comments is if you don’t say ולמחרתו it’s ambiguous as to whether you mean the next day Sunday or the following Sunday. By using ולמחרתו it removes all confusion.

Comment: @DonielF exactly my point. That's why I don't see what the problem is in saying this. And, as I stated, I've heard just about every Chazan always say it. It makes sense and avoids all ambiguities, besides being a good habit. Though, IMO, anyone that is really confused should just view the calendar, or ask his neighbor in English, Yiddish or Yeshivish.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=R9c9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA+%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%95+%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=h03Zbphsh-&sig=76Q9mkq0JxZe-rtAbImeT3wHm80&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL1YOktdvcAhXSmuAKHb67BGoQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D&f=false